# svn update does not replace deleted --- but not checked-in --- files

Tags: svn, command-line

I've got a version controlled directory where all sub-directories from many are - not clear how - deleted, and `svn status` labels them with "D". I've checked it with `svn ls -R <URL>` that they are there in the repo. I want to get these files into my local workarea. `svn up` tells me that my local directory with the only two subdirectory is up to date. I've tried `svn revert` to throw away any possible local changes, and also tried to update to the last used revision with `svn -r<number>`, but nothing changed. I should have the other files and sub-directories as well, but I have no idea how could I get them.
I use the `svn, version 1.9.5 (r1770682)` from linux command line.
How am debugging what is the issue, and how can I force the repo version of this directory to my local copy?

Comment: If you want to discard your local copy, why don't you just  delete it and checkout again?

Comment: It was already deleted from my working copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`svn up` will only restore files/directories which are labeled by `svn status` with a `!`.  Those are files that are simply missing.

`svn status` reports a `D` on files which are marked for removal (`svn delete`).  `svn delete` removes the file from disk and if you commit it (which is possible even though the file isn't there), they will be removed from the HEAD revision of the server.

To restore files labeled with a `D`, you are correct that `svn revert` is the solution.  Use `svn revert -R .` to recursively revert all local changes in the current directory and below.

Alternatively, use `svn revert path/to/missing/file` on each missing file.  That can be scripted on linux with:

```
svn revert $(svn status | sed -ne 's/^D//p')
```

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure what did I differently when I issued revert in the first place. Probably I missed the -R switch.

Comment: If you miss the `-R` switch, then it'll simply revert any directory properties in the current directory. It won't revert any children.